# Inconsistent behavior with `astimezone` utc offsets

Tags: python, datetime, timezone-offset

I have heard `datetime` and `pytz` don't play along perfectly (of course, managing time in code itself is tricky) and have seen many questions about daylight savings causing issues, but I'm experiencing what seems to be a more fundamental inconsistency.

Consider the following code with commentary:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

utc = timezone('UTC')
east = timezone('US/Eastern')

thing1 = datetime(2020, 2, 14, 9)
thing1 = thing1.replace(tzinfo=east)  # datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 14, 9, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)
print(thing1)  # 2020-02-14 09:00:00-04:56
thing1 = thing1.astimezone(utc)  # datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 14, 13, 56, tzinfo=<UTC>) 
print(thing1)  # 2020-02-14 13:56:00+00:00
# ^^^
# 4-hour 56-minute shift, as advertised.

thing2 = thing1.astimezone(east)  # Should undo the previous shift (fingers crossed)
print(thing2)  # 2020-02-14 08:56:00-05:00
# ^^^
# wut?  why a different shift?
```

I was expecting the output of that last line to be `2020-02-14 09:00:00-04:56`, coming full circle.

Sub-hour shifts were a bit of a surprise to me, but I was willing to roll with it. But it looks like `astimezone` knows how to shift east->utc, but does not invert the shift utc->east with the same offset.

What gives?  I find *lots* of reports of problems, but didn't strike upon something that explains exactly what I'm seeing.

Is there a simple way to get the offset to be consistent in both directions?

---

Note: I've been testing and it seems that the `delorean` module seems to solve this problem.  I'd be interested in knowing if it can be solved with standard library python, and also if the `arrow` module does it smoothly.

Comment: The answer is simply that `replace` does something other than `astimezone`. Don't use `replace` to make naïve datetimes aware.

Comment: @deceze  OK, but two questions: even if that line is wrong, why does astimezone shift by different amounts in the two directions?  2) The recommended way to create timezone aware objects is always to include it in the datetime constructor, then?

Comment: Read the two duplicates.

Comment: @deceze OK thanks: I hadn't refreshed my screen and did not see the duplicates.